# Access fragment method from asynctask postexecute

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I need some help to manage fragments and asynctask, I´ve search a lot in google and here in stackoverflow but I didn´t get a positive result.

I have an app with a TabsActivity and three tabs (fragments). One of them is a google maps. I´m trying to update the markers in the map with a get call throw a custom request class.

The problem is that I want to call a function in the fragment map class from the postexecute method. I have the context in the asyntask, I tried also passing the fragment as a parameter but I don´t know even in that way how to call the function. The Asynctask class is a file (it isn´t inside the fragment class).

Any help will be apreciated.

Regards.

P.D - sorry about my poor english :))

Comment: if you can show us some code then we can help you figure out what to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try passing your fragment to the AsyncTask like this:

```
class WorkerTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

  private MyMapFragment mapFragment;

  WorkerTask(MyMapFragment mapFragment) {
    this.mapFragment = mapFragment;
  }

  @Override
  protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
  {
    ...
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(Void res)
  {
     mapFragment.updateStuff(...);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Buddy, thanks a lot. I already tried in that way but it hadn´t worked. I tried another time and the problem was that the method in my fragment was private (fail) Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It got solved using a broadcastreceiver. This is how I did it:

```
class TabsTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    static final String BROADCAST_ACTION = "CALL_FUNCTION";

    @Override protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
         //some statements
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(String result) {  
         try {
            Intent broadcast = new Intent();
            broadcast.setAction(BROADCAST_ACTION);
            mContext.sendBroadcast(broadcast);
         } catch (Exception e) {
             //some statement(s)
         }
     }
     }
```

Now, in your fragment class:

```
private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        function_you_want_to_call();
    }
};

public void onResume() {
    //other statements
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(TabsTask.BROADCAST_ACTION);
    activity.registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
}

public void onPause() {
    //other statements
    activity.unregisterReceiver(receiver);
}
```