# Calling fragment method from a separate asynctask

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I have two fragments, Tab1 and Tab2.  Tab1 calls my AsyncTask, and in onPostExecute, I'm trying to get it to call a Tab2 refreshData() method.

I tried looking at [Access fragment method from asynctask postexecute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19184777/access-fragment-method-from-asynctask-postexecute) but I'm having trouble figuring out how to simply use Tab2 as an AsyncTask parameter.

Any insight or if there is a better way to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: hai We better see Codes you made

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make the `onPostExecute` method of your `AsyncTask` send a broadcast to a `Receiver` in your **Tab2** fragment.

**Broadcasting something: (in your AsyncTask)**

```
Intent intent = new Intent("someFilter");
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

You may also pass primitive types and objects as extras, using `putExtra()`.

**Receiving the broadcast: (in your Tab2 fragment)**

```
// declare the receiver as an atribute of your fragment
private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        refreshData();
    }
};

// add this to onCreateView
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mReceiver, new IntentFilter("someFilter"));

// add this to onDestroy
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
```

Pay attention to the `IntentFilter` you're using when creating the Intent and when registering the Receiver. They **must** match otherwise nothing will happen.

In summary, by using this, you won't need to pass the fragment as a parameter to your AsyncTask.